# Search the children for unknown children types in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to implemet a **Search settings** window that contains several GroupBoxes, to only view the corresponding ones. Each GroupBox contains several controls, so when the event `searchSettingsTextBox_TextChanged()` happen, I can search every GroupBox.Header & its childs for a text property (Text, Content, Header, ToolTip), if that GroupBox has it, make `gb.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;` otherwise make it `Visibility.Collapsed`, what I've done so far is:

```cs
private void searchSettingsTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GroupBox gb in wrapPanel1.Children)
    {
        if (!gb.Header.ToString().ToLower().Contains(((TextBox)e.Source).Text))
        {
            gb.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
        else
            gb.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

        foreach (var child in ((Grid)gb.Content).Children)
        {
            // Stopped here, can't check child.Text property which might be: (Text, Content, Header, ToolTip)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each of your possible controls (`TextBlock`, `TextBox`, `GroupBox`, `Label` etc) may have same properties (such as `Text` or `Content`), but represents different base class, so you can't work with them as with group of similar controls.

That turns you to manual type checks and following actions per specific control type.

Also, should be mentioned, that `Content` property (in `Label` for example) or `Header` (in `GroupBox`) is an **object** and may contain not pure string, but another control of even group of controls. It means that `Content` of some `Label` may be `TextBox` or `TextBlock` with `Text` property or `GroupBox` with `Header` property or even another child `Label` with own `Content`, so this chain may be quite huge and code, even recursive, may look like a complete mess.

With knowing it, even simple type cast-checks isn't guarantee for correct retrieval of *text* value (which means to represent its content) of control:

```
var controlTextValue = string.Empty;

foreach (var child in grid.Children)
{
    controlTextValue = child switch
        {
            HeaderedContentControl headeredControl => headeredControl.Header?.ToString(),
            ContentControl contentControl => contentControl.Content?.ToString(),
            TextBox textBox => textBox.Text,
            TextBlock textBlock => textBlock.Text,
            _ => null
        };
}
```

If you **sure** and have strict bunch of controls with content as *text*, than this way may do job for you.

Maybe it is possible to create a custom UserControl as a wrapper for any other control (for Framework/UI element as property/child), with some `SearchName` property and use it on search instead of iterating original childs properties. But i don't meet any such implementations to provide example, only pure idea and theory.

Comment: What is this syntax of "child switch" ? never seen it bf.

Comment: It's a switch expression (available from C# 8.0 and upper): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/switch-expression

Comment: Same common switch statement: https://i.stack.imgur.com/o7qFq.png. Or primitive if-else if statements: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZOwl.png. Sorry for screenshot-coding, don't see neccessity to edit/update answer to provide explanation for switches

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to walk through the visual tree.
Here's my implementation:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using static System.Windows.Media.VisualTreeHelper;


namespace CommonCore.Helpers
{
    public static class VisualTreeHelper
    {
        public static IEnumerable<DependencyObject> GetChildren(this DependencyObject reference)
        {
            ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(reference);
            Queue<DependencyObject> queue = new Queue<DependencyObject>(16);
            queue.Enqueue(reference);
            while (queue.Count != 0)
            {
                DependencyObject current = queue.Dequeue();
                int count = GetChildrenCount(current);
                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                {
                    queue.Enqueue(GetChild(current, i));
                }
                yield return current;
            }
        }
        public static IEnumerable<T> GetChildren<T>(this DependencyObject reference)
           where T : DependencyObject
            => reference.GetChildren().OfType<T>();

        public static T FindAncestor<T>(this DependencyObject dobj)
            where T : DependencyObject
        {
            while (dobj is not null)
            {
                if (dobj is T t)
                    return t;

                dobj = GetParent(dobj);
            }
            return null;
        }

        public static FrameworkElement FindDataAncestor<TData>(this DependencyObject dobj)
        {
            while (dobj is not null)
            {
                if (dobj is FrameworkElement element and { DataContext: TData })
                    return element;

                dobj = GetParent(dobj);
            }
            return null;
        }

        public static TData FindData<TData>(this DependencyObject dobj)
        {
            FrameworkElement element = dobj.FindDataAncestor<TData>();
            if (element == null)
                return default;
            return (TData)element.DataContext;
        }

    }
}
```

You can use the fact that the endpoint only outputs text to a TextBlock or TextBox.
Using this helper you can get all text values like this:

```cs
    string[] texts = someElement
                        .GetChildren()
                        .Where(el => el is TextBox or TextBlock)
                        .Select(el => el is TextBox tBox ? tBox.Text : ((TextBlock)el).Text)
                        .ToArray();
```

**P.S.** @Auditive rightly noted that some other elements also output text. For example Label, Button and other ContentControls. But if you expand their visual tree, it turns out that the final element responsible for displaying text is a TextBlock. Therefore, the code I suggested will work for them too.